# Creating ZigBee RGB Compatible Light - Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, light, zigbee, iot

I currently have a Rasberry Pi hooked up to a 64x32 LED matrix. It runs some custom Python scripts to control the colour and display of the matrix, which works great and lets me adjust the settings via a web interface.

I'd like to adjust the functionality so that it functions like an RGB smart bulb compatible with my current smart home system. I'm using HUE, which means the best way would likely be to use Zigbee - but I'm unsure of the best way to do this from a Pi.

I'm aware that I'll need to buy a radio for it to work (info on that would be great!), but I've not found a software solution yet either. I am using the GPIO pins to control the LED matrix at the moment, so they're unavailable.

I have found some resources for doing this with custom boards and/or Arduinos but of course that won't work for me - unless I can get the Arduino/other board to interface with the Pi somehow.

Appreciate any pointers - resources for the non-Pi projects are linked below.

TL;DR - how can I build a Zigbee compatible smart bulb on a Raspberry Pi, or on another board that can talk with a Pi?

https://peeveeone.com/?page_id=252
https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Mesh_Bee/
https://peeveeone.com/?p=187

Comment: Did you look at diyhue? Emulate a hue bridge, and control it that way.

Comment: @Passerby I already have a hue bridge - I'm not looking to make something to control hue devices, I'm trying to make a hue compatible device.

Comment: You can have more than one bridge to control.

Comment: Did you proceed with this project? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @tremby It's not really a solution to the problem, but as a workaround I started using home assistant to create a custom device that would operate by sending POST requests over WiFi instead.